# Write Status of test case with Hash Map and Selenium

Tags: selenium, junit, hashmap, status, data-driven-tests

I am using Hash Map to read the get excel data and use them in methods to perform If...else validations.

I am using class file for initializing the Hash Map for reading the data. it goes as shown below

```
public class SampleDataset {

        public static HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> main() throws IOException {

        final String DatasetSheet = "src/test/resources/SampleDataSet.xlsx";
        final String DatasetTab = "TestCase";

        Object[][] ab = DataLoader.ReadMyExcelData(DatasetSheet, DatasetTab);

        int rowcount = DataLoader.myrowCount(DatasetSheet, DatasetTab);
        int colcount = DataLoader.mycolCount(DatasetSheet, DatasetTab);

        HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

        // i = 2 to avoid column names
        for (int i = 2; i < rowcount;) {
            ArrayList<String> mycolvalueslist = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int j = 0; j < colcount;) {
                mycolvalueslist.add(ab[i][j].toString());
                j++;
            }
            map.put(ab[i][0].toString(), mycolvalueslist);
            i++;
        }

        return map;
    }
```

I am using this map in my testcase file which is as shown below

```
 @Test //Testcase
public void testThis() throws Exception {
    try {
        launchMainApplication();

        TestMain MainPage = new TestMain(tool, test, user, application);

        HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> win = SampleDataset.main();
        SortedSet<String> keys = new TreeSet<>(win.keySet());

        for (String i : keys) {
            System.out.println("########### Test = " + win.get(i).get(0) + " ###########");
            MainPage.step01(win.get(i).get(1));
            MainPage.step02(win.get(i).get(2));
            }

        test.setResult("pass");
    } catch (AlreadyRunException e) {
    } catch (Exception e) {
        verificationErrors.append(e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    }

}

@Override
@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    super.tearDown();
}
```

I want to write the status as PASS or FAIL for all the testcase initiated through above FOR-LOOP on to same excel by creating new column as Status for each row of test case

my excel sheet is as shown below

[image: SampleDataSet.xlsx]

Comment: Is the update excell file with the test status issue, or you do not know how to get test status information?

Comment: I do not know how to get the information in status column once i did the validation in teststep.

Comment: In for loop im trying to test Step01 and Step02 with a embedded methods for example here "MainPage.step01(win.get(i).get(1));" method is step01(string parameter). i am using if else to verify, I am ok with writing the console message in excel sheet under result coloumn, BUT HOW?

Comment: So you know the status (if you can write it in consol, you know it) and the number of row where you TC is stored, you just need to know how you can put it in excell, correct?

Comment: Yes exactly, as shown in the image i want my console to print on that Status column serially as test progress

Comment: See my answer, and mark it as accepted if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Cereate global List. After every test case add status result in the list.

After all test cases are finished, iterate trough te list and updete your excell file. In this way.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws EncryptedDocumentException, IOException {
    
    // Step 1: load your excel file as a Workbook
    
    String excelFilePath = "D:\\Desktop\\testExcel.xlsx";
    Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(excelFilePath));
    
    // Step 2: modify your Workbook as you prefer
    
    Iterator<Sheet> sheetIterator = workbook.sheetIterator(); // Getting an iterator for all the sheets
    while (sheetIterator.hasNext()) {
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheetIterator.next().rowIterator(); // Getting an iterator for all the rows (of current sheet)
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            // Put here your internal logic to understand if the row needs some changes!
            int cellsn = row.getLastCellNum();

            row.getCell(cellsn).setCellValue("String that you gat from List = list.get(rownumber)")
        }
    }
```

You may need Apache POI.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>5.00</version>
</dependency>
```